# Stop redirect page after wrong password

Tags: login

I use Divi Elegant Themes with Pop ups for Divi and Divi login module.

When user on my online store use wrong password site is refreshed and pop window was closed. Message about “wrong password” is also missing.

I think i need stop redirect page and load with opened Pop us and and also with message about wrong credentials.

Thanks for your reply.

If any informations is missing please send me a message and i will add.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Divi and the login module. Can you ask them for help? They'll know the code better than us.